# Trying to mount WD Passport, problems with permissions

Tags: steam, chromebook

I have Ubuntu working and downloaded on my Dell Chromebook, and I am trying to download Steam games onto my WD My Passport.

This appears after its plugged in and enter the password.
(https://i.redd.it/glom1umgiplz.jpg)

For the life of me I have no idea whats wrong, I am trying to successfully mount a passport drive and put a Steam folder on it. It is accessable through var/host/media/removable/My Passport.

When I select the pre created SteamLibrary folder

I get this as an error
(https://i.redd.it/zb0t3evtiplz.jpg)

Can I please get some help? What can I do to get the permissions and create the Steam game library

Comment: Using the terminal, type in `cd /media` then type in `ls -lah` and you should see a directory with your user name in it. Type in  `cd username` to enter that directory, and then type in `ls -lah` again. It should show your drive listed, including the ownership and permissions. Let me know the results of those commands

Comment: This is what I got: https://i.redd.it/6b3z1ckpnqlz.jpg

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit late to the show, but I recently managed to convince Steam to install games on an SD card on crouton ubuntu 16.04, and it was a tricky process. Steam, by default, doesn't allow itself to be run as root (you can't just punch in sudo steam in the command line, or it will tell you the same thing I just did), so you need to give each drive you use with steam permission to be run by it. How you do that is relatively simple in practice but hard to figure out for a novice. The goal of this will be to explain the process in a way that a novice like myself would understand.

Firstly, run gparted (`sudo apt-get install gparted`) if you don't have it already) and format whatever drive you want to use to ext4. This will make it unable to be used by windows/mac computers, sadly, but I tried it with fat32 and it didn't work. You're welcome to try others, but in my case ext4 is fine since the SD card is for use with my chromebook alone.

Then, run `sudo gnome-disks` in the command line. It's the standard disk utility, but you HAVE to run it as `su` for this next step. Once open, select the device you want to install to and unmount it. then click *additional partition options* (the button showing gears) and edit the mounting options like so: *uncheck auto-mount*, *check mount at startup*, check show in user interface. The fourth line beneath these are a shortcut to editing your fstab file; it's handy because it shows you the proper format right there instead of having to hunt for it online. Add ",exec" between some of the options that are already listed (nosuid,nodev,nofail,exec). Save your work, make a note of the mount point, re-mount the drive and close out of gnome disks.

Now your drive is mounting with exec permissions whenever you start up your device, but you're not done yet. Now you need to assign the folders with the correct permissions. A lot of guides online will tell you to run `chmod 777 -R path/to/folder`, but in my experience this doesn't work. Instead, we'll do it the GUI way. run `gksu nautilus` which will open the default file explorer with superuser permissions. Navigate to the drive's mount point (which was listed in gnome-disks under edit mounting) and right click the folder for your drive's ext4 partition. Click *properties* -> *permissions*. From here you can set things to what they specifically need to be, or you can just set permissions to open by giving everyone everywhere read, write and execute permissions. Close out of nautilus, and now it's finally time to open up Steam.

Now you should be able to tell Steam to create a folder in your drive by navigating to the mount point in Steam's file browser. It's embarassing how long it took me to figure this out and I'm sure there's a cleaner way to go about it, but this is the method that finally worked for me so I'm not going to try and clean it up.

Edit: if you're using crouton, you'll need to manually mount the disk each time prior to starting Steam. Alternatively, start steam, then mount it, then manually select the library folder.

Comment: Use `gksu` (GTK+ frontend for su and sudo) instead of `sudo` to run nautilus as root.